# Прочитать текст Java-программы и в каждом слове длиннее двух символов все строчные символы заменить прописными

Tags: java, io, task, filewriter, bufferedreader

Как должна работать программ.

- Прочитать код "Hello word"
- Заменить символы в словах, которые длиннее 2ух, на верхний регистр.
- Записать "обработанный код" в новый файл.

Моя программа успешно обрабатывает первую строчку, и записывает ее в файл, но со 2ой строчки уже идет, что то не то.

Мой код

```
package OptionalTask.Task4;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class fixed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("data/SomeJavaCode.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("data/Task4.txt");
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer)){

            String line = null;
            String word = null;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".{2,}");

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    word = scan.next();
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
                    if (matcher.matches()){
                        buffer.append(matcher.group().toUpperCase() + " ");
                    } else{
                        buffer.append(word + " ");
                    }
                }
                bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), 0, line.length() -1);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Код который считывает приложение по пути "data/SomeJavaCode.txt"

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloUser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите ваше имя: ");
        String pharase = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Доброго времени суток - " + pharase);
    }
}
public // test text
public
public
```

Результат, который записывается в файл по пути "data/Task4.txt"

```
IMPORT JAVA.UTIL.SCANNER; 
IMPORT JAVA.UTIL.SCANNE
IMPORT JAVA.UTIL.SCANNER; PUBLIC CLASS HELL
IMPORT JAVA.UTIL.SCANNER; PUBLIC CLASS HELLOU
IMPORT JAVA.UTIL.SCANNER; PUBLIC CLASS HELLOUSER
IMPORT JAVA.UTIL.SCANNER; PUBLIC CLASS H
IMPORT JAVA.UTIL.SCANNER; PUBLIC CLASS HELLOUSER { PUBLIC STATIC
IMPO

IMPORT JAVA.UTIL.S
IMPOR
IMPOR
```

Выглядит так, что приложение обработало весь изначальный файл. Привела где это требуется в верхний регистр (получается все слова длиннее двух символов). **Но начинает записывать каждую новую строчку, по новой и в одну строку.** Это и необходимо пофиксить.

Comment: как вариант можно формировать новый массив строк, которым заменят старый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую вам заменить **StringBuffer** на **StringBuilder**.

Дело в том, что в строке `bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), 0, line.length() -1);` у тебя индекс (который 0), постоянно считывает **с самого начала** твоего StringBuffer.

Из-за этого у тебя дублируются слова.

Советую добавить переменную `int offset = 0;`и заменить `bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), 0, line.length() -1);` на `bufferedWriter.write(buffer.toString(), offset, (buffer.length() - offset));`

Comment: Огромная благодарность за лекцию!:)